# Error while fetching data from Node.js rest api in Flutter ( Mysql Localhost)

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, flutter

**ERROR**: Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map')

```
Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async{ 
    final response = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull("192.168.43.106:8080/customers/"),
                                    headers: { "Accept": "application/json" } );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return Album.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    }
    else{
        throw Exception('Failed to load Album');
    }
}
class  Album {
final int id;
final String email;
final String name;

Album({this.id, this.email, this.name});

factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
  return Album(
    id: json['id'],
    email: json['email'],
    name: json['name'],
  );
}
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZSfq.png)

Comment: put some code here what you have tried instead of picture and show what's the actual error

Comment: Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async{
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull("http://192.168.43.106:8080/customers/"),
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json"
      }
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return Album.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    }else{
      throw Exception('Failed to load Album');
    }
  }

Comment: Can you share the Album Model code as well and the response coming from api?

Comment: @MuhammadNoman above is updated code. Please help

Comment: complete code link: https://github.com/Ebadullahamini/Ebadullahamini/blob/master/main.dart#L1

Comment: Response coming from API?

Comment: yes, i created node.js api and connected to localhos mysql and tested to postman and working fine. but in flutter it don't work.

Comment: Can you share the response coming from API? on Postman?

Comment: [
    {
        "id": 6,
        "email": "sami.nazari@gmail.com",
        "name": "sami",
        "active": 0
    }
]

Comment: Check below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response is a list of objects, not a single object. So you have to pass [0] index of your list.

Try below code, it will work for you.

```
Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async{ 
    final response = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull("192.168.43.106:8080/customers/"),
                                    headers: { "Accept": "application/json" } );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var str = jsonDecode(response.body);
        return Album.fromJson(str[0]);
    }
    else{
        throw Exception('Failed to load Album');
    }
}

class  Album {

  int id;
  String email;
  String name;

  Album({this.id, this.email, this.name});

  Album.fromJson(json)
    : id = json['id'],
      email = json['email'].toString(),
      name = json['name'].toString();

}
```